# how is an object created?

Tags: android

```
EditText text1; 
text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
text1.getText().toString();
```

Hi im new to android programming an need a little help. :) I just want to clarify if `text1` is an `object`? Because it can call a method. But if `text1` is an object how come that there is no "new" keyword. Thanks in advance for any response. :)

Comment: You don't need the `new` keyword because you are passed a reference to the object by the `findViewById()` function.

Comment: please learn Java basics before you continue, or you will get 1000 more questions like this

Comment: Oh i see so that findViewById() is like the "new" keyword.

Comment: The `new` keyword in this case is somewhere inside the `findViewById()` method, and it returns the `EditText` object.

Comment: Thanks . appreciate that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's me 2 years after, Now I want to answer your question bud. I know you just started and had a dream of creating apps that will be used by others, and guess what? You already achieved that and you can now also create apps not just for android but for IOS since you're using flutter now, you also have your own account on google play store now. Listen Bud, on the first line you declare what type is the text1. on the second line that's where you declare the text1 as an object now, then on the third line you are then using that object's capabilities like getting text. You've learned so much in this journey, and still learning not just in programming but in life.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that all variables do initialization with `new keyword`.

Like if you write

```
String s = "";
```

Your `String` has been initialized without `new keyword`.

Same like this `EditText` is provided initialization in `findViewById()`. Here `findViewById` returned `Edittext` instance.

**I suggest you complete Java Tutorial before continue work on Android. Because Android is based on Java language.**

Answer (score 0):

EditText is derived from the Super class View. Here findViewById method is returning an an object of the View class. You are explicitly typecasting it to EditText and assigning it to text1. So new is not required. It is being managed in findViewById method. Alternatively you can do this as:

```
EditText text1; 
text1 = new EditText(An instance of Context); //Create an object of Edittext class
```

Now do whatever with this object text1.

Comment: Thanks for the ans :)